# I want to convert my days format to seconds in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

In my dataframe I made a column for average delay which was the mean of a company's delay for clearing a certain amount. Since my average delay and delay contained negative values like -3 days , I was hoping that when I convert my average delay to seconds it will be negative too but it was positive. what did I do wrong?

```
avg_delay = maindata.groupby('name_customer')['delay'].mean(numeric_only=False)    


maindata['avg_delay'] = maindata['avg_delay'].dt.seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the `.dt.seconds` return at max 86400 seconds by [the pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.seconds.html)

`.dt.total_seconds()` might do the job, returning it as float64

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).